# packer image: copied file doesnt exists after image creation

Tags: image, packer

I am trying to create an image using packer. Using provisioned I am trying to copy files in VM and set/run then during VM creation so that image is ready to create another VM.

```
    "provisioners": [
     {
        "type": "file",
        "source": "index.html",
        "destination": "/tmp/index.html"
     },  
    {
        "type": "file",
        "source": "D:/Terraform/Azure-MongoDB/Azure-5/packer-trial/packer.zip",
        "destination": "/tmp/packer.zip" 
    },
    {
        "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .Path }}'",
        "inline": [
        "/usr/sbin/waagent -force -deprovision+user && export HISTSIZE=0 && sync"
    ],
       "inline_shebang": "/bin/sh -x",
       "type": "shell"
     }
    ]
```

Code creates image but not sure if the files are getting copied to require location or not. After creating VM and searching the file copy location is empty.

Comment: If you want the files to persist after the image creation, you will need to move them into the final location, other than `/tmp`, using a shell provisioner.

Comment: Thanks, Soltex. I now managed to overcome this.

Comment: Good to know. Did you move the files to another location as I suggested?